# Posting to wall after FB 'like' is not happening

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I've created a FB page and placed the Like button(Social ) for that FB page in one of my website.

when ever any user visits my website and clicks on the FB like button, the FB page is getting liked (happening perfectly) and after that a small popup are shown to post to facebook with our own comment. Whenever the user adds any comment its not posted to his wall.

Did anybody have the same problem?

And i've analyzed with some other test pages and its working fine but on some and not on some other. This behavior is very inconsistent on the pages.

Anybody have any solution or any idea why this must be happening?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. If I set the Like button URL to that of my website, then the comment posts fine. But for some reason if the Like button URL is that of my Facebook page, then the comment fails to post. Very frustrating.

Comment: @evanrmurphy but the thing, i can't find a bug related to this. FB dont have an official forum to answer. We can't track which is causing the bug as it's solely done from FB end.. Very very frustrating.. If you could found any solution, please let me know

Comment: I didn't find a solution, but I found a workaround. Instead of using the HTML5 like button code, use the iFrame one they provide. This one doesn't actually prompt the user for a comment at all, but that's better than prompting and eating the comment.